# How to create and call a pointer to a function

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

Hi I'm a beginner and I'm trying to work out some pointer to function examples.  I can't even compile my code, it shows the following message. I cannot determine why I am getting the compilation errors.

```
/tmp/cc0qghbo.o: In function `main':
pointer_to_function_inside_structure.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `func_ptr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is my code, please tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student_data
{
        char *name;
        int roll_num;
        int marks;
        void (* func_ptr)(struct student_data *ptr);
};

void print_data(struct student_data *ptr);

void print_data(struct student_data *ptr)
{
        printf("\nNAME OF THE STUDENT      %s", ptr -> name);
        printf("\nROLL NUMBER OF STUDENT   %d", ptr -> roll_num);
        printf("\nMARKS OF STUDENT         %d\n", ptr -> marks);
}

int main()
{
        struct student_data *ptr;

        ptr -> name = "ajish";
        ptr -> roll_num = 2;
        ptr -> marks = 50;

        ptr -> func_ptr = &print_data;
        func_ptr(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Your last line `func_ptr(ptr)` is using an undeclared variable `func_ptr`. You happen to have a field member with the same name, perhaps you intended `ptr->func_ptr(ptr)`?

Answer (score 5):

1. You're not allocating memory using your pointer.
2. Since `func_ptr` is a member of `student_data` you have to call your function using `struct student_data *ptr` which should be pointer to the instance of your struct.

Example:

```
int main()
{
    // allocate memory
    struct student_data *ptr = malloc(sizeof(student_data));

    ptr -> name = "ajish";
    ptr -> roll_num = 2;
    ptr -> marks = 50;

    ptr -> func_ptr = &print_data;

    // change this to:
    ptr->func_ptr(ptr);

   // free memory
   free(ptr);
}
```

Comment: +0: while this is right, it doesn't address the compiler error.

Comment: @AdamMaras: I've already suggested the OP to change `func_ptr(ptr);` to `ptr->func_ptr(ptr);` in my example.

Comment: @cpx I apologize, I did not see the comment in the code example. But you would do well to have mentioned why that line of code was changed in the body text of your answer.

Comment: please remove the cast of `malloc`'s return value. (Warning: the type `student_data` is not defined, you mean `struct student_data`!)

Comment: @kaizer.se: Thanks, I didn't notice that!

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(struct student_data));`  *without* casting the return value.

Comment: @kaizer.se VC++ compiler warns if i remove the cast `warning C4047: 'initializing' : 'struct student_data*' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'` but after looking at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) I think it is generally not needed. Thanks.

Comment: A C++ compiler would warn/flag for that issue. Anyway it's not horriby important.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the last line before `main()`'s closing brace from

```
func_ptr(ptr);
```

to

```
ptr -> func_ptr(ptr);
```

After that change, the program compiled and ran for me.  I compiled with gcc 4.5.0.

You should also either

1. Allocate space for `ptr` on the heap

   ```
   struct student_data *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct student_data));
   ```

   Don't forget to free it at the end of your program:

   ```
   free(ptr);
   ```

   Or
2. Declare `ptr` on the stack.

   ```
   struct student_data ptr;
   ```

   This will require you to change all your `->` operators on `ptr` to `.` operators.